# How to filter columns in dplyr specifying the column with a character object or a vector

Tags: r

I'm creating a function to filter a data frame using the dplyr package.

The name of the column changes and I'm able to specify it using a character object and specifying "one_of" See below:

```
 ICD=c("ICD.y")

 test<-filter(test1,one_of(ICD)=="9")
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : Variable context not set
```

The data frame test1 contains both the variable "ICD.y" and also multiple rows using with a value of 9. I would like to make this filtering by being able to assign the name of the column that I want to filter prior to using the dplyr filter function.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Albit

Comment: You may need `filter_` instead of `filter`

Comment: Is there be any additional change I would need to make? I still get the same error using filter_: Error: Variable context not set

Comment: It used to work earlier.  Try with `interp` i.e. `test1 %>% filter_(lazyeval::interp(~col ==9, col = as.name(ICD)))`

Comment: This worked. Thanks Akrun!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with `interp` from `lazyeval`

```
library(dplyr)
test1 %>% 
      filter_(lazyeval::interp(~Col ==9, Col = as.name(ICD)))
```

Comment: Would this work with vectors longer than one element as well? ie. ICD=c("ICD.x","ICD.y")

Comment: @albitpaoli  No, it won't work unless you are creating a filter with `|` or `&` based on the two columns

Comment: Ok. It would be nice to be able to filter a pre-specified group of columns using the same criteria. ie all columns in specified vector == "1".

Comment: @albitpaoli  This you can do easily in `base R` i.e. `test1[Reduce('&', lapply(test1[ICD], '==', 1)),]`

Comment: Great!! Thanks Akrun